# Decide whether vectors are linear independent

Tags: linear-algebra

We have $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ...,\alpha_n$ set of $n$ vectors in linear space $V$
such that every $n-1$ subset of vectors is linear independent. The question is if this condition is sufficient to state that all vectors $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, ... , \alpha_n$ are linear independtent ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Consider $\alpha_1 = \alpha_2$ for $n=2$.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand it correctly. For $n=2$ we have $a\alpha_1=0$ and $b\alpha_2=0$ implies that $a=b=0$, but if $\alpha_1=\alpha_2$  then $k=a\alpha_1+b\alpha_2=\alpha_1(a+b)=0$ hence we have for instance $(a,b)=(2,-2)$ and $k=0$ . Is my reasoning OK ?

Comment: @John Yes, it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just take $n-1$ linearly independent vectors $v_1,v_2,\dots,v_{n-1}$ and set
$$
v_n=v_1+v_2+\dots+v_{n-1}
$$
If
$$
\beta_2v_2+\dots+\beta_{n-1}v_{n-1}+\beta_nv_n=0,
$$
then
$$
\beta_nv_1+(\beta_2+\beta_n)v_2+\dots+(\beta_{n-1}+\beta_n)v_{n-1}=0
$$
forcing $\beta_n=0$ and so $\beta_2=\dots=\beta_{n-1}=0$.

The same for proving that any other subset of $n-1$ vectors is linearly independent.